# How to copy powershell help files to mac

Tags: macos, powershell

I need to learn using the Powershell Get-Help for school, but on mac the Update-Help does not work.

For some reason commands like 'Get-Help about_Functions -online' do not work either. I have downloaded the help files from my windows computer and would like to copy them to my macbook. I cant find any information on where to put the files. Can anyone help me.

Comment: What do you get when you run `Update-Help`?

Comment: Try this to update the help manually: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-saved-help-files-to-update-powershell-help/

Comment: When i update it manually i get the error "Update-Help : Failed to update Help for the module(s) :
'PSDesiredStateConfiguration, ThreadJob'
The Update-Help command failed because the specified module does not support updatable help. Use Get-Help -Online or look online for help for the commands in this module."

Comment: Try doing `Update-Help -Force -Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. Look at the `Update-Help` documentation so you know what these do